# Encode french characters using UTF-8

Tags: character-encoding, portlet, websphere-portal

When I submit a jsp page and the request goes to a portlet controller, I want the french characters on the jsp page to be encoded always using UTF-8 in the portlet controller.
What is the code syntax that I need to use in jsp or portlet controller to ensure this?

Answer (score 0):

For me works

```
  <%@ page language="java" import="java.util.*" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
```

in the top of the JSP